# Cannot get starting point for random movement simulator

Tags: python, simulation

I'm trying to create a program that runs a basic simulation.
Create a row of ten boxes, let a random number generator pick which direction he moves, and keep track of him.
The problem for the last while now is that the initial position is not being friendly.
I want to start in the middle - five - but no matter where I put that line, I get an error.

Here's the code:

```
import random


def right_movement():
    p = p + 1
    m = m + 1
    times[p] = p
    print times


def left_movement():
    p = p - 1
    m = m + 1
    times[p] =+ 1

def main():
    p = 5
    times = [0] * 11
    times[p] = 1
    m = 0
    print times

    while p >= 0 and p <= 10:
        x = random.randint(0, 1)
        if x > 0:
            right_movement()
        else:
            left_movement()
    if p == 11:
        print "Movement to the right into location 11."
        print "Number of moves is " + m + "."
    else:
        print "Movement to the left into location 0."
        print "Number of moves is " + m + "."


main()
```

No matter where I put `p = 5`, I get an error in reference to that. I'm running Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to something called [scope](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php).

In a nutshell, what you did is you first created a variable called "p" within your `main` function. However, that does not mean that the other functions you create will be able to know that `p` exists.

I think this might be easier to understand if I give an example. In the first line of `right_movement`, you do `p = p + 1`. Since you're using `p` to add 1 to it, Python is going to look to see if you've assigned the variable `p` within `right_movement`. Since you didn't, it's going to sort of "move up" a layer, and see if you assigned the variable `p` within the file in general. Since you didn't assign `p` in either of those (you assigned inside `main`), Python will give up.

There are several solutions to this. The quick-and-dirty one would be to use something called "global" variables, and would look like this:

```
import random

p = 5
m = 0
times = [0] * 11

def right_movement():
    global p
    global m
    global times
    p = p + 1
    m = m + 1
    times[p] = p
    print times



def left_movement():
    global p
    global m
    global times
    p = p - 1
    m = m + 1
    times[p] =+ 1
    print times



def main():
    times[p] = 1

    print times
    while p >= 0 and p <= 10:
        x = random.randint(0, 1)
        if x > 0:
            right_movement()
        else:
            left_movement()
    if p == 11:
        print "Movement to the right into location 11."
        print "Number of moves is " + str(m) + "."
    else:
        print "Movement to the left into location 0."
        print "Number of moves is " + str(m) + "."

main()
```

You move the `p`, `m`, and `times` variables outside of the `main` function to the file, and make sure to use the `global` keyword to let Python know that you want to modify the variables inside the function, rather then temporarily creating a new one.

However, this isn't the cleanest solution -- [using global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485020/646543) is considered bad practice for a variety of reasons.

A better solution might be to keep track of the state within `main`, and rewrite your code to look like this:

```
import random

def right_movement(times, p):
    p += 1
    times[p] += 1
    return p

def left_movement(times, p):
    p -= 1
    times[p] =+ 1
    return p

def main():
    p = 5
    moves = 0
    times = [0] * 11
    times[p] = 1

    print times
    while 0 <= p <= 10:
        moves += 1
        x = random.randint(0, 1)
        if x > 0:
            p = right_movement(times, p)
        else:
            p = left_movement(times, p)
        print times
    if p == 11:
        print "Movement to the right into location 11."
        print "Number of moves is " + str(moves) + "."
    else:
        print "Movement to the left into location 0."
        print "Number of moves is " + str(moves) + "."

main()
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Maybe explain why `times` works, being defined in `main()` but updated in the functions (whereas this caused problems for `p`)?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to share the same variables among several functions, without passing the values in to the functions as arguments. In order to do this, you need to use *global* variables.

Something like this:

```
import random
p = 5
times = [0] * 11
m = 0

def right_movement():
    global p, times, m
    p = p + 1
    ...
```

So, first you need to declare the variables outside of any function, then you need that *global* statement in each function that uses the variables.